# Enyo onbeforeunload Event

Tags: javascript, events, dom, enyo

I'm trying to attach a listener for `onbeforeunload` in my app but it doesn't seem to be caught by `enyo.Signals`.

According to the [Documentation](https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Event-Handling):

> Within the Enyo framework itself, DOM events that have no node targets are broadcast as signals. These events include window events, like onload and onbeforeunload, and events that occur directly on document, like onkeypress if document has the focus. Signals are also useful for hooking up non-Enyo events (e.g., PhoneGap events) to be handled by Enyo kinds in application code.

I wrote the following test case:

```
 enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    kind: "enyo.Control",
    fit: true,
    content: "Hello World",

    components:[
        {kind: "enyo.Signals", onbeforeunload: "test"}
    ],

    test: function(inSender, inEvent) {
         return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    }
});
```

This seems to have no effect when I close the tab or navigate away from the page. What am I missing? Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xH3Vd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like we are handling beforeunload by default:

https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/blob/master/source/dom/dispatcher.js

But, you can get it to work with something like

```
enyo.dispatcher.listen(window, "beforeunload");
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be better to call this in my app or add it to the windowEvents array in dispatcher.js?

Comment: It's probably better to add this in the app.

Comment: Can you please give me the `beforeunload` app code. or any jsFiddel example

Comment: Sure, this is really simple and hard to find the log message, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/sugardave/KaLxZ/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I got this error in my app. "enyo.kind.inherited: unable to find requested super-method from -> undefined in enyo.Signals"